# DocuSign API: webhook notifications for embedded signing ceremonies

Tags: docusignapi

While we can receive webhook messages for email signatures, it seems that DocuSign does not send a webhook event for an embedded session signature.  Does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docusign supports webhook events via two ways -

1. Account level - Connect Configuration: 
   For this, you need to configure the webhook URL. Go to Docusign Admin page -> under Integrations, select "Connect" -> Add Configuration -> Custom -> Specify the webhook URL and the triggering events.
   This will apply to all the envelopes of that account.
2. Envelope level: 
   Add following to the createEnvelope request:

```html
 "eventNotification" : {
    "URL": "<webhookurl>",
  "loggingEnabled": "true",
  "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
  "useSoapInterface": "false",
  "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
  "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false",
  "includeDocuments": "true",
  "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "true",
  "includeTimeZone": "true",
  "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "true",
  "includeDocumentFields": "true",
  "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "true",
  "envelopeEvents": [
   {"envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent"},
     {"envelopeEventStatusCode": "delivered"},
     {"envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed"},
   {"envelopeEventStatusCode": "declined"},
   {"envelopeEventStatusCode": "voided"}
  ],
  "recipientEvents": [
   {"recipientEventStatusCode": "Sent"},
   {"recipientEventStatusCode": "Delivered"},
   {"recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed"},
   {"recipientEventStatusCode": "Declined"},
   {"recipientEventStatusCode": "AuthenticationFailed"},
   {"recipientEventStatusCode": "AutoResponded"}
  ]
 }
```

This applies to that envelope only.

You can configure the events on which you want the webhook URL to be triggered.

DocuSign hits the webhook on the corresponding events with a XML which contains all the information about the envelope and recipient events. You can also configure if you don't want to receive the signed document in XML.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Connect can fire events for Embedded Signing events.

Are you using an account-level Connect configuration, or envelope-level EventNotifications?

Answer (score 1):

The events related to an embedded signing session are `recipient` events vs the broader `envelope` events. -- So check that your Connect subscription is asking for the right events. Eg recipient_completed, not just envelope_completed.

In addition, the default Connect queuing strategy will usually combine notifications for events that happen at almost the same time.

For example

1. Recipient 1 signs (via embedded ceremony or email-initiated ceremony)
2. The envelope is now complete (recipient 1 was the last recipient for the envelope)

If you've asked for recipient and envelope events, you'll usually only be notified once for the above two events.

If you want individual notifications for each of the above events, switch to using SIM queuing for Connect. This is done at the Account level via the Updates section of the eSignature Admin tool.